# Replicating Rows without for loops

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have the following data table:

```
DT <- data.table(c("A","B"), c("a;a;b","c"))
```

which outputs:

```
   V1    V2
   1:  A a;a;b
   2:  B     c
```

I am trying (without using for loops) to create an output using data table methods that looks like:

```
       V1    V2
   1:  A     a
   2:  A     a 
   3:  A     b
   4:  B     c
```

I've been able to do something similar by counting the number of elements separated by ";" and then duplicating rows. From there, I loop to change the values but this seems quite slow and I think I'm missing something obvious.

Thanks!

Comment: There's `splitstackshape::cSplit(DT, "V2", ";", direction="long")`. Looking to see if there's a matching dupe (previous question)

Comment: The answer I posted was `DT[, setNames(strsplit(V2, ";"), "V2"), by = V1]`. This is already covered in the linked dupe by Jaap's answer